# How should I build a history from a text in rails effective

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm looking for some suggestions to build a history in a database effective, from a text which changes over time.

The only idea which I have at the moment is, to calculate the difference between the "old" and the  "new" text. And save this difference in the history tabel from the text.

But the big question for me is, how can I show the change between two versions. If I only save the difference, the connection between the "old" and the "new" text gets lost.

Regards, dot

Comment: Thx both! Is there a **possiblity to change the table name** of the paper_trail. Because I extend a existing tool, which has already a table with the name "versions" which i should not change.

Comment: possiblity to change the table name => we can do.see my updated answer,sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `paper_trail` gem to save the versions,paper_trail having lot of feature and simple to use.

And documentation also well defined.

Add PaperTrail to your Gemfile.

```
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.1'
```

Generate a migration which will add a versions table to your database.

```
bundle exec rails generate paper_trail:install
```

Run the migration.

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Add `has_paper_trail` to the models you want to track.

More info [Rails casts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail) and in [github](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)

Use different table for version [see this](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#custom-version-classes)

Comment: is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem called `paper_trail` which you can use to track changes and revisions.

https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

> PaperTrail lets you track changes to your models' data. It's good for auditing or versioning. You can see how a model looked at any stage in its lifecycle, revert it to any version, and even undelete it after it's been destroyed.

You can find documentation on github on how to implement it.

There's an excellent [RailsCast on implementing Undo with Paper Trail.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail)